# Last $n$ digits of a fibonacci sequence number, and first $n$ digits.

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to solve a puzzle that will lead me to some GPS coordinates.

The puzzle is this:

The first seven digits of the GPS coordinates are the first seven digits of a fibonacci number that has 1,224,418 digits.

The next seven digits are the last seven digits of $F(n)$ where (it's a single integer)

$n=16180339887498948482\\04586834365638117720309\\1798057628621354486227\\05260462818902449707\\2072041893911374848290908$

I am aware that Fibonacci numbers' last digit cycles at a period of 60 numbers. This, however, only gets me the last digit of the second part of the GPS. The creator of this question claims that no computing is necessary. How would one go about finding the answer?

Comment: Hint : Use Binet's formula and the logarithm to base $10$. It is not true that no computation is necessary, but you need not calculate the fibonacci-number itself.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your answer. I have tried to use the Binet's formula but I am unsure about how to use it in this problem, especially with the logarithm you mentioned.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding
Now take the log10 of two numbers with the same starting digits (diffrent lengths)